# How to improve the quality of the images which are generated by Kabeja?

Tags: java, image, dxf

I am developing a project using [kabeja](http://kabeja.sourceforge.net/) package and I was able to use it to generate image from DXF file and I need to know how to improve the generated image quality using kabeja package.
Please can some one explain how to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the page size, length and width while generating image

```
<property name="paper" value="A3"/>
<property name="width" value="420mm"/>
<property name="height" value="297mm"/>
```

Refer to kabeja-0.4\blocks\svg\conf\process.xml and set the parameters accordingly.

Comment: Where should I chage this properties ? How to do it in netbeans IDE?